# ¿Cómo puedo eliminar el espacio utilizado por unos botones en el xml en android?

Tags: android-studio

Tengo al final de un `Scrollview` dos botones: un *botón guardar* y un *botón cancelar*; están establecidos como invisibles, pero queda todo el espacio que estos ocupan en al final del `xml`.

Quiero saber como al estar estos botones invisibles no se note ese espacio que utilizan y al volverlos visibles por medio de otro botón se vuelva a crear este espacio y se muestren. ¿ Alguna idea ?

Comment: Hola MarkTicus, ¿Cual es el .xml?, trata de agregar información necesaria para que la comunidad te ayude a solucionar el problema de una forma correcta, revisa [ask], por cierto no se te olvide realizar el [tour] del sitio, saludos!

Answer (score 1):

Para que no ocupen espacio debes sustituir tu actual atributo:

```
android:visibility="invisible"
```

Por este otro:

```
android:visibility="gone"
```

Via Java:

```
tu_vista.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

De esta forma estarán invisibles pero no ocuparán espacio alguno y se saldrán del flujo.

Cuando quieras que sean visibles de nuevo, de foma dinámica haces lo siguiente:

```
Tu_vista.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

**Nota:** Para ocultar un control en un layout se pueden utilizar las siguientes propiedades:

1. **Visible:** muestra el control
2. **Invisible:** oculta el control
3. **Gone:** oculta el control y éste no ocupa espacio